# Can I redirect to a local file using Python Flask?

Tags: python, http, flask

I have an HTML file I've generated which contains links that are serviced by Flask routes. On handling a click-through, Flask does some twiddling, and then does one of two things:

- Either redirects to an external bog-standard URL, or;
- Redirects to an MP3 file stored locally on disk.

I'm using Flask to redirect clicks to the external links using `return redirect(url, 302)`. This works fine.

I want to play the MP3 files in the browser, and so want to do a similar redirect to something like `file://path/to/file.mp3`.

Setting `url` to point to this and calling `redirect()` doesn't seem to work; the browser gets stuck at the Flask route path.

I'm assuming it's my knowledge of HTTP and Flask that's failing on this occasion. What's the best way to achieve what I want to do? I was thinking something like `send_from_directory()` wasn't what I wanted...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do that with `javascript`, just render an simple html page that have `<script>document.location ="file://path/to/file.mp3"</script>`

Comment: Most (if not all) browser's security settings won't allow you to access files using the `file://` protocol when the current page is loaded via `http://`, they'll simply block it. You'll need to server the files through http...

Comment: Ok, thanks @mata, I hadn't realised this. I'll go the Apache route...